# Include one child in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a class column:

```
class Column
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   field :label, type: String
   field :typ, type: String
   field :parameter, type: Hash

   belongs to :entity
end
```

and I have a class Entity:

```
class Entity
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   field :label, type: String
   field :description, type: String
   field :typ, type: String

   has_many :columns
end
```

In my controller I want to return all all Entities with a certain ids:

```
result = Entity.where(:id.in =>rels)
render json: { result: result}
```

But additionally I also want to include the the field *parameter* from the column with *name* : 'status' which shall be called _actions. That would be the ideal solution.

Example I have the Entity Record:

```
{ _id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  label: 'Test',
  description: 'Test',
  typ: 'Test'
}
```

And I have a column:

```
{ _id: 2,
  name: 'status',
  label: 'Testxxx',
  description: 'Testxxx',
  typ: 'Test',
  parameter: { a: 'xxx', b: 'yyy},
  entity_id: 1
}
```

The result want to have rendered as:

```
{ _id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  label: 'Test',
  description: 'Test',
  typ: 'Test',
  _action: { a: 'xxx', b: 'yyy},
}
```

But I would be happy if my results contains the column 'status' or worst case, even all columns. Any ideas? I've been working hours to find a solution.

Comment: you can define an `as_json` method in the model whose field you want to rename and in there you'd have access to the `self` object where you can do the name change,`def as_json; self[:_action] = self[:parameter]; end;`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I include this single child? I tried to include all columns with: *Entity.include(:columns).where(xxx)* and I created an *as_json* to include the columns but the columns array was always empty.

Comment: Found a solution - not sure its the best one:

Define a method on class entity *_actions* which looks for the column with the name status and returns its *parameter* field. Include method *_actions* as an option in the as_json call.